# Fatal Error HRESULT=0x80131c08 while debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I am running Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit in VMware 4.1.1 running on 2 processors and roughly 2GB of ram. On debugging a simple application Visual Studio seems to hang/unresponsive. I then get a bubble message informing me that "Visual Studio is busy waiting for an internal operation to complete". After a few minutes I then receive the following prompt:

"A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. For more details, please see the Microsoft Help and Support web site. HRESULT=0x80131c08. ErrorCode=0x0."

Microsoft's Support website can't find a solution. I have searched my favourite resource 'Google' to no avail. As well as looking here on stack overflow. I did find a post on here similar but unrelated to VMware, post mentioned that this error was due to a memory issue, so I increased the virtual machine to 4GB and tried the whole process again. And got the same error.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or found a solution or could point me in the direction of the right thread. As I say I did search to no avail.

Comment: The exception code means "debugger timeout", that will come as no surprise.  Never seen this, something about your setup is pretty messed up.  Change the setup.

Comment: thanks for response...vs setup or vmware setup?

Comment: Machine setup.  So yes, probably vmware.

Comment: So have tried adjusting various settings in VMware, still have the same issue. I will try a different project this evening see if it still occurs if so will try setting up a new virtual machine. Forgot to mention above that I get a 'Delay Notification' while Visual Studio becomes unresponsive, will add to explanation above.

Comment: Enough reason to dump the VM and just install VS2010 on your main OS?

Comment: Would if I could, but reason I am running it in VM is it's on my iMac at home. Maybe I will try bootcamp as another option. Although not ideal as I like to switch quickly between design applications and VS2010.

Comment: I've got the same error on my computer running Windows 8 natively without any virtualisation. Computer is freshly installed, and the error occurs only sometimes and only when I exit the program.

Comment: I had this same thing happen to me 3 or 4 times in different spots when debugging a C# application using native code debugging, VS 2010 was installed natively on a Windows 7 machine with approximately 8 GB of RAM, ~2 GB free. I was stepping through the assembly code behind `Thread.SetApartmentState()` if it matters. I just started the program normally with debugging.

Comment: I am having a similiar problem, again debugging C++ from C#, using VS2015 Enterprise. I suspect the C++ code has a bug or two, but finding those bugs is going to be very difficult if the debugger keeps on timing out. Again the C++ code involves much string manipulation. I suspect a buffer overflow, then I suspect when the garbage collector attempts to do its job it can not for some reason and everything freezes up for 5 minutes until one finally gets HRESULT = 0x80131c08.

Comment: To add to above comment I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This had nothing to do with my configuration, VMware / Memory. I am embarrassed to say it was completely my fault. Issue in my code with an array, although I have never been able to cause Visual Studio to crash before with my own code. Apologies for wasting your time @Hans Passant.

Comment: What was the issue exactly? I'm running into the same problem, but I can't spot any obvious problems with my code.

Comment: I get this error, too, sometimes when I exit my application, so I'd love to hear more Information about this - did you corrupt your heap or what was the array problem?

Comment: To be honest I cannot remember the exact issue with my code as I just simplified it in the end. I can however tell you that I was trying to group multiple address lines into a string array and set that in a single property as a concatenated string. Ended up separating it out into multiple address properties.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the problem I am having. I am writing code to print the 23 attributes of a class into a CSV file. If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a waste- these 8 years later and I have the exact error code newing up an array in old code I found. If not for your posting, I'd be still looking.

Answer (score 7):

I had this error when I automatically attach to a process in C# code using the EnvDTE namespace. The process that was attached unexpectedly ended (the process was killed somehow?) and therefore the debugger timed-out. Probably a unlucky moment, after that message with the HRESULT=0x80131c08 error I also got another message saying: could not not detach from proces X (the automatically attached process) due to a unrecoverable API failure.
Hopefully this might be of some help so some one some day.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this error (among others) when attaching WinDbg (non-invasive) to a process while the VisualStudio 2013 debugger is attached.  If you ask why I'd even do such a thing, it's because VS 2013 no longer supports loading SOS into the VS debugger!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was a stack overflow, I checked for possible stack overflows (in my case it was a model property calling itself) and fixed it, then the issue resolved.